# Database Design for Webapplication Collection

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-services, database-design

My aim is to write a collection of many webapplications, like google services (mail, calendar, docs, ...).

It will be written in PHP with Zend Framework (Version 2). I use MySQL to store data.

The service collection should always be extendable (new services) easy.

Is it useful to provide a own database for every service? They would have few tables only (more or less 3). That would mean that I have to use Zend's multiple database adapter.

The other solution is to use one big database for the hole collection. The advantages are that I can use foreign keys between the tables of different applications. I also could use the default database adapter.

All the applications are enmashed with each other close.

What makes more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break the services out with one database each, including the service that identifies the users. All of the services should talk to each other via web services. This architecture will be the most flexible in terms of scaling pieces individually as well as maintaining the pieces individually.

It is impossible to give anything more specific in terms of architecture of such an application ecosystem without substantially more information about the project, and incidentally, that would be beyond the scope of this site to answer.

Comment: Thanks! Part I don't understand: How do the talk to each other? BTW: Can you give me an advice via mail?

Comment: @sharethis - Web services, via REST, are a common choice for inter-application communication, but there are a number of options. I am available for consulting. Please examine the source code of the website linked to in my StackOverflow profile for a contact address.

Comment: I will read about web services and rest. Contact you next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough databases from your provider you could use multiple databases, but if you have User accounts its better to create one main-Database for that.

Comment: There are no restrictions for the number of databases. It's only limited by webspace. Wich case of user accounts?

Comment: If you have user accounts for all those services (like a Google ID for Mail, Calendar, ...) you could store that user data (email, password) in a main database...

Comment: My idea was to store the authentication data in a independent database. Why do you think "its better to create one main-Database for that"?

Comment: well "My idea was to store the authentication data in a independent database" is exactly what I meant, or do you store the authentication data in every database (like in calendar, mail, notes, ...)?